# Apache: i want each user have it's own DocumentRoot e.g. ~/www

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

i want to configure Apache2 so that each user have his/her own DocumentRoot and instead of `/var/www` put the files in `/home/john/www` (john is a username smple)

Answer (score 2):

[The Apache manual has that covered](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/public_html.html). Basically, you need to enable a module in your server configuration, set the local path and you're done. In your case, the local path should be something like:

```
UserDir /home
```

This automatically expands to `/home/username`.

In my opinion, though, going with a `public_html` folder (or similar) is better. This allows your users to store data that is *not* accessible via web.

Comment: Agreed, this is the setup that I use.

Answer (score 2):

You want Apache's mod_userdir module:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html

Specifically, search your existing configuration files for "UserDir" (might be in the main httpd.conf, in extra/httpd-userdir.conf, or in some other file depending on where you got Apache.)  Uncomment it and set it to this:

```
UserDir www
```

Remember to enable the mod_userdir module (or uncomment "Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf" in httpd.conf, whichever applies) to allow the module to be loaded!

Comment: thanks, what about ownership and permissions of `www`?

Comment: @takpar it would work under apache user and group so you would need to either give the right chmods or to create a virtualhost for each domain using suExec and suPHP so both, php and py,perl etc would work under that given user.